# "Modification of a read-only value" on while loop with implicit $_ variable

Tags: perl

I don't really understand why the following piece of perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

strange($_) for qw(a b c);

sub strange {
  open FILE, '<', 'some_file.txt' or die;
  while (<FILE>) { } # this is line 10
  close FILE;
}
```

Is throwing the following error

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at ./bug.pl line 10.
```

Is this a bug? Or there is something I should know about the usage of the magic/implicit variable `$_`?

Comment: Keep in mind that `while (<FILE>)` is a shortcut for `while (defined($_ = <FILE>))`.

Comment: For search engine keywords, I'd like to add this title variation: **“Modification of a read-only value” on $_ variable, in relation with a _while loop_ on a _file-handle_** - as it seems to be a commonly related construct/cause of this issue (I just ran into it and came here)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `while (<fh>)` construct implicitly assigns to the global variable `$_`.

This is described in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators):

> If and only if the input symbol is the only thing inside the
>   conditional of a while statement (...), the value is automatically
>   assigned to the global variable $_, destroying whatever was there
>   previously. (...) The $_ variable is not implicitly localized. You'll
>   have to put a local $_; before the loop if you want that to happen.

The error is thrown because `$_` is initially aliased to a constant value (`"a"`).

You can avoid this by declaring a lexical variable:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    # do something with $line
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems one learns something every day. `for` localizes `$_` in the same scenario, but for some reason `while` does not.

Comment: @TLP, The reason that `while` doesn't localise `$_` is that `while` doesn't modify `$_`. Keep in mind that `while (<FILE>)` is a shortcut for `while (defined($_ = <FILE>))`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the while-loop reads into `$_` which at that point is aliased to a constant (the string "a"). You should use `local $_;` before the while-loop, or read into a separate variable.

Comment: Good to know, I thought perl would automatically do that for me.